# How to load JS last in IE 8 and 7

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok.. So I have done a bit of research and haven't found much on this. So was wondering if someone can enlighten me.

I like to load my Script at the bottom of the page like below

```
<html>
  <head>
    CSS Goes here
  </head>
    <body>
       <div id="container">
       </div>
       <script></script>
       <script></script>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Which works fine in all modern browsers but I found in IE 8 and 7 the JS had to be in the head instead of in the body for it to work. So was wondering why and what the work around is as I would prefer to load JS files after everything else.

Thanks

Comment: Any reason why it should be included at the bottom? And why it doesn't work in IE8- ? Can u post the script?

Comment: Loading JavaScript at the bottom is a great way to avoid halting until the DOM is finished to start rendering the HTML

Comment: http://developer.yahoo.com/blogs/ydn/high-performance-sites-rule-6-move-scripts-bottom-7200.html

Comment: What doesn't work about it with it being in the body?

Comment: Before end of body tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Comment: Why does it only work while in the head? Must be something wrong with your JS.

Comment: "I found in IE 8 and 7 the JS had to be in the head instead of in the body for it to work" - well, it sounds like the issue is specific to your JavaScript. Hard to answer without a demo that's broken in IE7/8.

Comment: Are you using `document.write` anywhere?

Comment: I've used this technique many times. It has no issue with IE. You are doing something incorrectly. Post your code and we can probably help you figure it out =D

Comment: You could be running into the bug where IE7/8 doesn't allow you to modify the document.body from within the document.body, but we can only speculate since you haven't provided any code.

Comment: try creating an onpageload handler that uses document.write to add a script tag that loads your javaScript.

Comment: @DwB wouldn't using document.write after page load destroy the page?

Comment: I believe document.write will append at the end of the document.

Comment: @DwB in IE document.write destroys the original document

Comment: wow alot of stuff here, demo is up at here:madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/ give me a chance to change over the scripts

Comment: It appears that document.write is not a good way.  Here is a reference article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice  I recommend against using W3Schools as a reference.  Here is a mozilla article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load

Comment: hmm but that shouldn't effect it working though I'd of thought. And im using document.ready, off the top of my head for all of them

Comment: I think the problem is that I'm bundling my javascript to make it load faster. When I do it all seperatly then it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. Really shocked how many people have responded

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just figured this all out. 
Basically I needed to load all the js at the bottom apart from the htmlshiv js file which I have now put in my head, works fine now.

Jquery only manipulates html so its fine to load it after the html but the shiv actually reprograms the way a browser loads html so it need to be loaded before the html.

Thanks very much everyone